# Bokeh graphs y_range coordinate off by half a coordinate

Tags: python, bokeh, scatter-plot, frequency, tfidfvectorizer

I am displaying the frequency of nouns in a dataframe using bokeh charts.
The data consists of companies and their patents from which I extracted the nouns.

When I display the frequencies using a y_range of (0,10) the data is displayed perfectly. When I use the list of companies, the data is offset by half a y_range coordinate.

```
scatter = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200, 
             x_range =  max_words, 
             y_range = companies,                
             tools = tools
            )
```

[image]

compared to

```
scatter = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=200, 
             x_range =  max_words, 
             y_range = (0,10),                
             tools = tools
            )
```

[image]

any suggestions of how this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are providing a list of categorical factors e.g. `y_range=companies` then the actual coordinate values in the *data* also need to be the same (string) categorical factors, not numbers.

There is an underlying synthetic coordinate system for categorical ranges, which is why passing numbers "works" in any sense at all. But doing this is not the intended usage, and there is no guarantee that the mapping from categorical factors to (internal) synthetic numeric coordinates won't change at any time (i.e. it should not be relied upon).

See the User's Guide chapter [Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) for more information and many examples.

Alternatively, if you really want to keep numerical y-coordinates, you could use a FuncTickFormatter that converts the integer coordinates into company names to display, in order to "fake" a categorical y-axis.

Comment: So I guess I probably need a 3D dataframe lie a panel or xarray.This would align the nouns with companies?

Comment: Sorry,  I don't see how that follows at all, or how that is even related, to be honest. You are clearly already using categorical coordinates (i.e. *string* values) correctly on the x-axis. You just need to do the same exact thing on the y-axis. If you are saying that you are already doing that, then you would need to provide a ***complete minimal reproducer*** so that there is no speculation about what you've actually done in code.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really want to keep numerical y-coordinates, you could use a `FuncTickFormatter` that converts the integer coordinates into company names to display, in order to "fake" a categorical y-axis

Comment: post your FuncTickFormatter cooment as an answer so that I can tick it as the answer. Thank you for the answer.